# gradle(spring boot): @id symbol not found

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, gradle, entity

(Entity class)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKdWy.png)

(Error message)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kq6YN.png)

dependency[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDeDl.png)

dependencyAnother @Entity annotation is fine. but only @id annotation is not working...

(dependency)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Change from `@id` to `@Id`, case matters.

Answer (score 0):

The error mesage is self-explaining. Java is case-sensitive programming language. `id` and `Id` are not the same here. You **have to** use `@Id`.